# MSSQL connection fails with correct login credentials

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this C# database class which is causing me error:

> Can not open connection! The method or operation is not implemented.

Here is the class:

```
using System;

namespace selister
{
    class Program
    {

        public void connect ()
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connetionString = @"Data Source=MYLAPTOP\\MSSQLSERVER02;Initial Catalog=Selister;Trusted_Connection=True";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
             p.connect();   
        }
    }
}
```

The full exception is :

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
    at selister.SqlConnection.Open() in C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive - Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\
        selister\SqlConnection.cs:line 16 
    at selister.Program.connect() in C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive - Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\
        selister\Program.cs:line 22
```

This is how I connect to mssql using SQL server management studio
[image]

Comment: Post the full exception, not just the message. If the code you posted failed with a `NotImplementedException` nobody would be able to connect to SQL Server. Something else is going on. You can get the full exception with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Are you an admin?  The only reason I see if you are an Admin that it would fail.  Try starting VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  VS does automatically run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Here is the full error message: Can not open connection ! System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at selister.SqlConnection.Open() in C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive -  Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\selister\SqlConnection.cs:line 16
   at selister.Program.connect() in C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive -  Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\selister\Program.cs:line 22

Comment: Line 16 is: `string connetionString = null;`

Comment: Line 22 is: `cnn.Open();`

Comment: Look what the call stack says: `C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive - Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\selister\SqlConnection.cs:line 16` Your project has a custom `SqlConnection` class. It's using that, not the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` class

Comment: Did you right click on `Create type` when you got an error by mistake, instead of choosing to import the correct class?

Comment: It seems like there was another file generated (not by me, or maybe I touched something) and it's called `SqlConnection.cs` I deleted that but now I have red lines under `SqlConnection` in `Program.cs` @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Add the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package. That class wasn't added by itself, it was added in response to a developer action. Someone clicked on the `Create type SqlCollection` suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full exception text shows that your code is calling a custom `SqlConnection` class, not the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` class.

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
 at selister.SqlConnection.Open() in C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive - Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\selister\SqlConnection.cs:line 16 
 at selister.Program.connect() in C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive - Company SA\Bureau\selister\selister\selister\Program.cs:line 22
```

I suspect you wrote the code first and when you got an error that the `SqlConnection` class is missing you clicked on the `Fix` icon and selected `Create Type` which created a new empty class whose methods all throw a `NotImplementedException`. You probably intended to click on `Import` instead, which would have added the `System.Data.SqlClient` package and added the correct `using` statement

You should delete your custom class, add the [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) package to your project and add the correct namespace to your code. Your code should be rewritten to use `using` blocks, to safely close connections even in case of errors:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;


namespace selister
{
    class Program
    {

        public void connect ()
        {
            string connetionString = = @"Data Source=MYLAPTOP\\MSSQLSERVER02;Initial Catalog=Selister;Trusted_Connection=True";
            try
            {
                using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection Open ! ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection !\n " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing this **System.Data.SqlClient;** is the reason for your error which is used to import the SQL Server Connection library files :

Attached below Code is for your reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{

    public void connect()
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = "Data Source=SERVER NAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASE NAME;Trusted_Connection=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! " + ex.Message);
        }
       }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.connect();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I posted your code and I had errors line under the two `SqlConnection` mentions

Comment: Plz make sure that you had imported these **using System.Data.SqlClient ** libraries above --@Display name

Comment: I did, I basically copy/pasted your code and only changed the connection string

Comment: Please explain what type of error is that while compiling

Comment: @Displayname you didn't add the library or package, you're using your own custom library by mistake

Comment: `Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1069  The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.    selister    C:\Users\john.smith\OneDrive - COMPANY SA\Bureau\selister\selister\selister\Program.cs    17  Active
`

Comment: Plz check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd356223-f729-44b3-9dd1-ade28b3386e1/the-type-or-namespace-name-sqlconnection-could-not-be-found